# How to ensure user input within a given valid range?

Tags: java, loops, validation

I am currently working on a code to produce a hollow square made of asterisks from 1-20. Here is what I have so far, but I am unable to figure out how to loop the code back on itself if the user enters a number > 20. If the user were to enter 21, for example, the code still creates the asterisk square and pops up the "Invalid Size. Enter Size from 1-20:" text underneath to re-prompt the user, but a new number does not result in anything. I need it to not create the square (if > 20 or <= 0) but "jump" straight to the Invalid Size text and then create a square if the user's input is within 1-20. If their input is again > 20, I need it to again prompt invalid. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much for taking the time to read this. :)

```
import java.util.Scanner; // program uses class Scanner

    public class HollowSquare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // variable declaration
        int x;
        int s;
        int p;
        int r = 0;
        int y = 1;
        int z = 1;
        int f = 1;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Enter the Size of the Asterisk Square from 1-20: "); // prompt user
        x = input.nextInt();  
        if (x > 0 || x <= 20);

        // read and store data from user
        s = x + 2;
        p = x - 2;

        // print output
        while (y <= x) 
        {
            System.out.printf(" * ");
            y++;
        }
        while (r < p) 
        {
            System.out.print("\n * ");
            while (z <= p) 
            {
                System.out.print("   ");
                z++;
            }
            System.out.print(" * ");
            r++;
            z=1;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        if (x > 1)
        {
            while (f <= x) 
            {
                System.out.printf(" * ");
                f++;
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
        else
                System.out.printf("\n");

     // conditions
        if (x <= 0 || x > 20)
            System.out.println("Invalid Size. Enter Size from 1-20: ");
            x = input.nextInt();
    } // end main method
} // end class HollowSquare
```

Comment: Did you consider looping until you get satisfactory input?

Comment: `if (x > 0 || x <= 20);` does  nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I am still very new to coding. I can remove that if statement, I thought that was what put the parameters on this code. That looping would work! I am unsure how to add that though.

Comment: Please take the [tour] at your convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop until you get satisfying input:

```
int x=0;
/*   ... */
while (x < 1 || x > 20)
{
    System.out.printf("Enter the Size of the Asterisk Square from 1-20: "); // prompt user
    x = input.nextInt();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's some code that solves your problem.

It uses a recursive function that calls itself again if it doesn't succeed.

if(blah blah blah); does nothing (it does the expression before semicolon = nothing.)

ifs work like this:

if(blah blah bla){

code

code

code

}

note the curly brackets.

what you do in python with identation, you usually do with curly brackets in java.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // program uses class Scanner

public class HollowSquare {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        drawSquare();
    }
    public static void drawSquare() {

        // variable declaration
        int x;
        int s;
        int p;
        int r = 0;
        int y = 1;
        int z = 1;
        int f = 1;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Enter the Size of the Asterisk Square from 1-20: "); // prompt user
        x = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()); 
        if (x > 0 && x <= 20){

        // read and store data from user
        s = x + 2;
        p = x - 2;

        // print output
        while (y <= x) 
        {
            System.out.printf(" * ");
            y++;
        }
        while (r < p) 
        {
            System.out.print("\n * ");
            while (z <= p) 
            {
                System.out.print("   ");
                z++;
            }
            System.out.print(" * ");
            r++;
            z=1;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        if (x > 1)
        {
            while (f <= x) 
            {
                System.out.printf(" * ");
                f++;
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
        else
                System.out.printf("\n");

     // conditions
    }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Size. Enter Size from 1-20: ");
            drawSquare();
}
    } // end main method
} // end class HollowSquare
```